# Unknown entity namespace in security.yml with custom entities folder in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, namespaces, entity

I have my model entities saved in `src/AppBundle/Model/Entity`.

You can understand, that i have own custom folder for entities (in model folder).

This is my orm settings in config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: false
    mappings:
        user:
            type: annotation
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Model/Entity
            alias: 'Entity'
            prefix: AppBundle\Model\Entity
            is_bundle: false
```

I have a problem with these lines in my `security.yml`:

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username
            # if you're using multiple entity managers
            # manager_name: customer
```

There is some error:

```
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'AppBundle'.
```

I don't what ref I have to use (`AppBundle:User` probably not).

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried `AppBundle\Model\Entity\User` ? You could also try to change prefix to `AppBundle:` not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thank you Vadim, i tried it and it works. Sorry I am beginner in Symfony, and sometimes i have problems with basics (routing, refs etc.)

Answer (score 2):

By default, all Symfony bundles will have a nice alias: `XxxBundle` (aliasing the `NamespaceOfXxxBundle\Entity` namespace). As you're bundle doesn't follow this convention and stores it in `Model\Entity` instead, you have 2 options:

1. Don't use the alias feature and pass the FQCN: `AppBundle\Model\Entity\User`
2. Create a new alias, give it a nice name and use it:

   ```
   doctrine:
       orm:
           # ...
           mappings:
               user:
                   type: annotation
                   dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Model/Entity
                   alias: App # <-- the alias name
                   prefix: AppBundle\Model\Entity
                   is_bundle: false
   ```

   ```
   App:User
   ```